# Sending multiple mails from a single method in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I have a simple mailer

```
class ApplyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def inform_teacher
  end

  def inform_division
  end

  def inform_everyone
    inform_teacher.deliver
    inform_division.deliver
 end
end
```

Calling `inform_teacher` and `inform_division` everything works well. But when I try to call `inform_everyone` just one blank email arrives.

Is it possible to combine multiple email method though one method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to this:

```
class ApplyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def inform_teacher
  end

  def inform_division
  end

  def self.inform_everyone
    ApplyMailer.inform_teacher.deliver
    ApplyMailer.inform_division.deliver
 end
end
```